# How Do I get to know which com port my USB modem is connected to? Is there any command?

Tags: networking

Please help me i am unable to connect to internet.
When i connect using network manager i connects only once the it does not detect my modem.

Comment: Windows sets up virtual com ports for USB devices. `lsusb -t` will provide a tree showing how all your usb devices are connected. I hope this clarifies things for you

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Your question would be clearer if you were to add details like what you tried to fix it and what happened when you did. I can only hope my answer is helpful as the information you've provided is a bit limited. In future please help us help you by reviewing http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask You are likely to get usable answers a lot faster if you follow those guidelines. I thank you and the community thanks you!

Comment: I wish it would Elder

Answer (score 2):

You can get a tree of USB devices with `lsusb -t`

```
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/8p, 480M
```

True serial ports can be detected with the command `dmesg | grep tty`

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.526866] 00:07: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

You can set and/or report serial information with `sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123]`

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
```

if setserial isn't installed already you can install it with `sudo apt-get install setserial`

Comment: How will i install setserial without connecting to the internet on my ubuntu system

Comment: Download the appropriate deb package for your release of Ubuntu here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/setserial

Comment: i have tried to install many .deb packages but they still need net connection to install

Comment: @AbhishekRana http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Answer (score 1):

Execute following command in terminal :

```
lsusb
```

It will look like this [image]

You see the device 004 : .... shows logitech Inc, it is the port where my usb mouse is attached, check your usb devices and see the name of your modem corresponding to device 00X.

[Check this for more info](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/lsusb.8.html)

Comment: If it solves your problem, click the grey ☑ under the "1" at the left of the text, which means "I accept the answer"

Comment: So if it says 002 for my Huawei modem then i should type ttyUSb01 for it or what.